# Getting an error, "full_output = 1 to get quantitative information. warnings.warn(warning_msg, ODEintWarning)" while solving my ODE

Tags: matplotlib, plot, graph, scipy, ode

[The trajectories are created, but with a warning message.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rUDR0.png)I am trying to solve my ODE with some parameters. For g=0, it is working adeuately, but for other values of g, it gives me a warning and an incomplete solution. I tried to increase the stepsize, but no effect has been seen.
I also rechecked system of equations, but no clue has been found.

I tried increasing the stepsize in the odeint function, but still got incomplte trajectories of solutions. My system is a second order ODE. I even tried to set limits. Any help would be appreciated in figuring the problem.

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.integrate import odeint
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

m=0.5
g=0.9
time=np.linspace(-10,10,200000); #time interval tried to increase number of points between intervals.
def system(phi,t):
    phi_1=phi[0]
    phi_2=phi[1]
    dphi1_dt=phi_2
    H=np.sqrt((8*np.pi/3)*(0.5*(phi_2**2))
              +(0.5*(phi_1**2)*m**2)+(g*(phi_1**3)))
    dphi2_dt=(-3*H*phi_2)-(phi_1*m**2)-(3*g*phi_1**2)
    dphi_dt=[dphi1_dt,dphi2_dt]
    return dphi_dt

init=np.linspace(-0.2,0.2,5)#initial conditions set
init_2=np.linspace(-0.2,0.2,5) #initial conditions set

for i in init:
    for j in init_2:
        phi=odeint(system,[i,j],time,mxstep=50000000)#my try
        plt.plot(phi[:,0],phi[:,1])#phase portrait
plt.xlabel("$\phi$",fontsize=12)
plt.ylabel("$d \phi/dt$",fontsize=12)
plt.xticks(fontsize=12)
plt.yticks(fontsize=12)
plt.xlim(-0.2,0.2)#visualization limits
plt.ylim(-0.2,0.2)#visualization limits   
im2=plt.show()
```

Comment: Can you add the problem output to the question?

Comment: Edited Question. See the figure, attached.